Judgmente in Romans 2 and divine election
My question has to do with the relationship between the judgment of Romans 2 and the doctrine of election. If God in the election decides to choose some from among the condemned mass, and the condemnation spoken of is the one that alludes to the final judgment, what is the importance of the judgment by works in Romans 2?  According to Paul the judgment is to determine who has life or who has death, that is, who is elected and who is reprobate. In the context of divine election the judgment does not determine salvation since it is the decree, so what Paul says does not make sense.  It is not the judgment that determines destiny but the decree.

"the condemnation spoken of is the one that alludes to the final judgment" - could you rephrase that?
More than writing things in a confusing way, I believe you have missed the point of Romans 2 (which is part of a larger section, namely chapters 1-3). Verses 7, 8 + 9, and 10 outline three categories of people, which are elaborated on in verses 12-16, 17-24, and 25-29 (respectively). We are all under the same judgement, ultimately, as 3:9ff explains.

Sorry, English is my second language.
Calvin defines predestination as the creation of some people for life and others for death. Romans 2 expresses that life and death have to do with God's final verdict on the works of men. This makes sovereign election a decreed judgment. Romans 2 would be revealing this eternal decree, not really judging the works that have nothing to do with the sovereign election. How to harmonize what Romans 2 teaches with the sovereign election that determines the destiny of men before creation?

Romans 1 primarily shows that the sin seen in irreligious men deserves death.
Romans 2 shows that the pride and hidden sin of religious men also deserves death.
The result is summarized in [Rom 3:12 ESV] All have turned aside; together they have become worthless; no one does good, not even one." followed by the good news in [Rom 3:22-24 ESV] the righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ for all who believe. For there is no distinction: for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, and are justified by his grace as a gift, through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus
There are other passages which more directly deal with election, if that is the main issue you wish to discuss:  Check some of the existing questions on election for passages that are election related.

My question has to do with the relationship between the decree of reprobation and salvation with the judgment. If the decree establishes who is lost or saved without relation to works according to Romans 9:11-12, what is the use of a judgment by works when the decree has already determined the destiny of each one? According to Paul, Romans 2 deals with the final judgment, and the decree has to do with the final destiny.

[Jhn 8:21 ESV] 21 So he said to them again, "I am going away, and you will seek me, and you will die in your sin. Where I am going, you cannot come."  The judgement is the backdrop, the default position of all men.  What we do condemns us.

Thanks for taking the time, but your response don't deal with my question. I will like to know how people deal with this problem: Judgment and predestination. Thanks a gain.

Saul - The most important thing to remember is that a man is responsible for his own decisions - predestination is no excuse for behavior.  Does this passage help? [Eze 33:18-19 ESV]  When the righteous turns from his righteousness and does injustice, he shall die for it.  And when the wicked turns from his wickedness and does what is just and right, he shall live by this.

Thanks Brian. Both Romans and the Ezekiel quote only affirm that God judge men according to their works. If you were to explain the doctrine of judgment with the decree of reprobation and the decree of salvation in mind, how would you do it? Taking into account, as Calvin affirms, that God created men for different purposes, some for salvation others for damnation. would we not be speaking of a judgment whose verdict was already established by decree? Hence the question arises: What is the purpose of the judgment, of people whose destiny were already predestined?

Realization. To bring into reality; make real. God spoke the world into existence - it wasn't enough just to think it or speak it, it had to become real.  Similarly, Christ had to really suffer and die to ascend to the throne - it was not enough to be qualified and willing, it actually had to be done.  It is not enough to be elected president, one needs to be sworn into office.  It is not enough to have an appointment, one must go to it. It is not enough to be guilty under the law - one must be formally sentenced, then actually face the judgement.  Does that help?

Thanks Brain. If we understand by election what Calvin affirms that not all were created for the same purpose, some for life and others for death, the destiny of all was already determined on creation. If this is true, the judgment in Rom 2 does not determine the future of men, but the decree of God. In Romans 9 Paul maintains that the election is not by works, while in Romans 2 the final destiny is determined by works. If I affirm Rom 9 I have to deny Rom 2, or vice versa. The last Judgment will be just an affirmation of the decree.

All men deserve and are headed to hell.  Jesus paid our debt, but we must choose to accept His payment in our place by believing God sent Christ. Regardless of your view on Calvinism, you will only be saved by trusting in Jesus, and receiving His righteousness in place of your own (which is like  filthy rags per  Isaiah 64:6).  The key question is -  Have you done that? Whether you believe in predestination, or a free will uninfluenced by God, you are destined for the lake of fire if you have not. Let me know:  Have you chosen to trust in Jesus, regardless of what comes?
